DXF with incomplete Gauß Krüger Zone 4 Coordinates
I have a DXF file (dwg originaly). The Coordinates in said file are set in Gauß Krüger Zone 4 (wich was used in Bavaria, Germany around 20 Years ago.
While loading the File in QGIS (3.28.15) the drawing is correct and the most important attributes are there.
BUT The Drawing is locatet anywhere but where Germany is suposed to be (I have around 5696 kilometer deviation).
I actualy know why said Problem is occuring. The coordinates are coded without the leading numbers.
Example:
A Point in the DXF (viewed with dwgTrueView)
X 388954.0610   Y 435399.1420
The Point how it should lokk in GK Z4
X 4388954.0610   Y 5435399.1420
The fix would be fairly Easy, would it be a csv table, where i could put it in.
Can I tell my QGIS it has to add those leading numbers or that it thinks those leading numbers are there so that I can get the DXF in the correct position?

@Paul van der Kroft I have no Idea where I have to put the Command in.
Is this ogr2ogr a Command starter or a Plug?
If the latter, I don't know where to get that and I don't know where to put in Commands in general.

The problem could be solved. it took a while but the solution of @Paul van der Kroft helped.
So did the solution From @Mike-EZUSoft. But be aware, it seems every layer, that is marked as not visible in the dxf is ruled as not visible in the imported Version. wich in my case is not changeable, because i cant save these dxf parameters with trueview. In QGIS you can disable that ruling.

Have you tried using the Field Calculator?

Please put the updates as comments and if an answer worked for your mark it as correct answer this will help the community. Thanks.

Please use these instructions to merge your accounts: https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts


Disclaimer: I am the developer of this plugin

Use the plugin "AnotherDXFImporter". It has a move function built-in


Point how it should look in GK Z4 X 4388954.0610 Y 545399.1420

The Y-value is not correct. There is a missing place.
4388954,061 5445399,142
or
4388954,061 5545399,142
or
...


You are correct. That was a typo from me. More than one apparently the correct Y value would be 435399.1420
When you can't copy paste becouse of two different PCs yikes.
Unfortunatly i cant get AnotherDXFImporter to work. I can install the Plug, but i don't find the plug anywhere, not even whith the searchbar (lower-left-corner).
i couldn't find it in none of the tree QGIS versions I have installed (3.34.; 3.28.; 3.22.)

After the installation of the plugin the functions can be find at:
Menue Vector --> DXF Import/Convert
See also http://www.makobo.de/links/Dokumentation_AnotherDXF2Shape?lang=EN

One could use DB Manager to create a virtual layer to move all geometries over the desired distances (x, y and z). For the purpose of the following example, let's suppose that the layer is named "dxfimport" and the output should contain columns "id" and "layer" from the original file. This query should then re-position all geometries:
SELECT id, layer, ST_Translate(geometry, 4000000, 500000, 0) AS geometry
FROM dxfimport

Press "Execute" and then "Load as new layer" (entering a suitable name for the new layer).
EDIT:
If translating a single layer is not enough, it might be better to (bulk) translate the source. Apparently the source is a GeoPackage with many layers. The entire GeoPackage can be translated with a single command, using `ogr2ogr.exe`, and a copy of that utility is shipped with Qgis.
Here's an example:
ogr2ogr.exe -f GPKG [output_file].gpkg -gcp 0 0 4000000 500000 -gcp 1 0 4000001 500000 -gcp 1 1 4000001 500001 -gcp 0 1 4000000 500001 -order 1 [source_file].gpkg
The translation is done using ground control points (multiple options "-gcp src_x src_y dest_x dest_y"). In the given example the added `-order 1' is probably superfluous; you might try it without.

Thanks yes that does the trick.

Unfortunately the DXF produced a LOT of Layers (or a few badly mangable, if I merge them.). although they are all safed in one GPKG.
I have to change every one manualy.
I couldn't figure out how to work that magic for the whole gpkg.
